# update a particular nested list in react native

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I'm developing an app which allows users in the group to join any group of thier choice. I have the group name displayed in a list. When the user taps on a button for a particular row and accepts to join the group, a value in that particular row is suppose to change.

```
handleJoinGroup = (item) => {
  Alert.alert(
    'Join Group',
    'Sure to Join ' + item.name + '?',
    [
      {text: 'No', onPress: () => console.log('no')},
      {
        text: 'Yes',
        onPress: () => this.setState({'isUserJoined':'1'}),
        style: 'cancel',
      }
    ],
    {cancelable: false},
  );
}
```

View

```
{
  item.isUserJoined == '0' ? 
  <Button
   containerViewStyle={{width:'50%', alignSelf:'flex-end', position:"absolute", top:0, right:-25}}
    onPress={()=>(onJoinGroup(item))}
    rounded = {true}
    style={{margin:10}}
    icon={{name: 'add'}}
    backgroundColor='#03A9F4'
    buttonStyle={{borderRadius: 0, marginLeft: 0, marginRight: 0, marginBottom: 0}}
    title='Join Group' 
  />
  : null
}

{
  item.isUserJoined == '1' ? 
  <Button
   containerViewStyle={{width:'50%', alignSelf:'flex-end', position:"absolute", top:0, right:-25}}
    onPress={()=>(onExist(item))}
    rounded = {true}
    style={{margin:10}}
    icon={{name: 'trash'}}
    backgroundColor='#DC143C'
    buttonStyle={{borderRadius: 0, marginLeft: 0, marginRight: 0, marginBottom: 0}}
    title='Exit Group' 
  />
  : null
}
```

When the user accepts to join a group i want the value of `isUserJoined` to change to 1 so it updates the view

Comment: you are changing the state and comparing the item.isUserJoined  item is data not state

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to update button's view and functionality onClick. that means on first    click user join the group and second click on same button user exit the group.

By this method you can add more buttons (Groups) with same functionality.

```
this.state = {
  isUserJoined: null,
}
...

isUserJoin(groupNo) {
  if (this.state.isUserJoined) {
    this.setState({ isUserJoined: null })
  } else {
  Alert.alert(
   'Join Group',
   'Sure to Join ' + item.name + '?',
   [
     {text: 'No', onPress: () => console.log('no')},
     {
       text: 'Yes',
       onPress: () => this.setState({ isUserJoined: item }),
       style: 'cancel',
     }
   ],
   {cancelable: false},
 );
  }
}

render() {
return (
<Button
  containerViewStyle={{width:'50%', alignSelf:'flex-end', position:"absolute", top:0, right:-25}}
  onPress={()=>this.isUserJoin('1')}
  rounded = {true}
  style={{margin:10}}
  icon={{name: 'add'}}
  backgroundColor={this.state.isUserJoined ===  '1' ? '#03A9F4' : '#FFFF'}
  buttonStyle={{borderRadius: 0, marginLeft: 0, marginRight: 0, marginBottom: 0}}
  title={this.state.isUserJoined ===  '1' ? 'Join Group 1' : 'Exit Group 1'}
/>
)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Depending on how you store and pass data to your components, you should either use `this.state.isUserJoined` (if you accessing it directly from your App component) or `this.props.isUserJoined` (if you accessing it from child component via props)